# Is my free tier over?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, billing

I created an aws account a year ago. And I reserved a t2.small instance for 1 year. Now I want to switch to t2.micro and I was wondering if I am still eligible for free tier? During the previous year I was also using ESB 30gib under the free tier.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about AWS admin - not programming

Comment: From [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/): Amazon EC2 "Expires 12 months after sign-up".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your free tier is over. The free tier is up to 1 year from the date of your AWS account creation

Even AWS do let you know whenever you are about to launch any Instance whether is it in the free tire or not.

[image]